# I need to select the attribute given of a node that have an attribute named TypeCode with a value of REF, i can't find the right XPath query

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to select the attribute "given or family" of a node that have an attribute named TypeCode with a value of REF, i can't find the right XPath query

```
   <participant typeCode="IND">
      <associatedEntity classCode="giver">
        <associatedPerson>
            <name>
                <given>Administrator</given>
                <family>test</family>
            </name>
        </associatedPerson>
    </associatedEntity>
</participant>
<participant typeCode="REF">
    <time value="20151013000000+0200"/>
    <associatedEntity classCode="PROV">
        <associatedPerson>
            <name>
                <given>TestBIB1</given>
                <family>Train1B</family>
            </name>
        </associatedPerson>
    </associatedEntity>
</participant>'
```

Comment: named `Type` or `typeCode`?? Also "select the attribute given of a node that..." needs to be rephrased in order to be understandable: Can't you add to your question what node you want to select in your example document fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select any node with attribute `typeCode="REF"`, use the XPath:

```
//*[@typeCode="REF"]
```

To specifically select `participant` elements with the attribute `typeCode="REF"`, use the XPath:

```
//participant[@typeCode="REF"]
```

To then select the given/family elements, use:

```
//participant[@typeCode="REF"]/associatedEntity/associatedPerson/name/given
```

or

```
//participant[@typeCode="REF"]/associatedEntity/associatedPerson/name/family
```

Comment: i need to take the valye family or given at the second participant

Answer (score 0):

A possible XPath would be

```
//participant[@typeCode="REF"]/associatedEntity/associatedPerson/name
```

which selects both the `given` and `family` elements.

You need to clarify what you mean with "given or family", and if you need to select the text content, etc. This will likely lead to some tweaking of the expression above.